# How to merge two columns in a pandas dataframe, stacked on top

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1
  sample x data       data y
         b              a
         d              c
         f              e
         h              g
         j              i
         l              k
```

I need to create a new dataframe like this:

```
information  identifier
b       x
d       x
f       x
h       x
j       x
l       x
a       y
c       y
e       y 
g       y
i       y
k       y
```

Can this be done in pandas? It's like stacking one column on top of another but keeping a record of what type of information the column is. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by columns names and then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) :

```
#first data solution
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = (df.unstack()
       .reset_index(level=[1,2], drop=True)
       .rename_axis('identifier')
       .reset_index(name='data')[['data','identifier']])
print (df)
   data identifier
0     b          x
1     d          x
2     f          x
3     h          x
4     j          x
5     l          x
6     a          y
7     c          y
8     e          y
9     g          y
10    i          y
11    k          y
```

EDIT:

If use `melt` then columns names create new column:

```
df = df.melt(var_name='identifier', value_name='information')
print (df)
       identifier information
0   sample x data           b
1   sample x data           d
2   sample x data           f
3   sample x data           h
4   sample x data           j
5   sample x data           l
6          data y           a
7          data y           c
8          data y           e
9          data y           g
10         data y           i
11         data y           k
```

So you can extract values `x` and `y`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(x|y)', expand=False)
df = df.melt(var_name='identifier', value_name='information')
print (df)
   identifier information
0           x           b
1           x           d
2           x           f
3           x           h
4           x           j
5           x           l
6           y           a
7           y           c
8           y           e
9           y           g
10          y           i
11          y           k
```

Comment: can you see the edits I've made to the question? Is there a way to do this using pd.melt?

Comment: @Muzz - it is similar like unstack, what is logic for `x` and `y` values from columns names?

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is quite intuitive:

1) Split the columns and create a new dataframe with the values of x_data and 'x' as identifier for the other column (the same with 'y_data')

```
dx = pd.DataFrame(zip(df['x_data'].values.tolist(),['x']*(len(df['x_data'].values.tolist()))),columns=['data','identifier'])
dy = pd.DataFrame(zip(df['y_data'].values.tolist(),['y']*(len(df['y_data'].values.tolist()))),columns=['data','identifier'])
```

Consider this piece of code:

```
zip(df['x_data'].values.tolist(),['x']*(len(df['x_data'].values.tolist())))
```

What we are doing here is making two lists: 1st one with the values of x_data; 2nd one is a list with 'x' repeated for every element in x_data
With zip we convert them in a single list and use the pd.DataFrame([list,columns]) to produce dataframe dx

2) Concatenate the dataframes to deliver a single one with the expected format

```
df = pd.concat([dx,dy])

print(df)
data identifier
0    b          x
1    d          x
2    f          x
3    h          x
4    j          x
5    l          x
6    x          x
0    a          y
1    c          y
2    e          y
3    g          y
4    i          y
5    k          y
```